# How to use the Context API to pass one state & function to multiple different components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I working on React for 6 months now. I am struggling with this issue only now because the Context API is pretty new to me. I love it, but I don't know how to correctly use it, to clean up and optimize my React APP.

I have this problem, where I have fetching data with Axios in each component with the same function and same state in each component.

I am actually copy-pasting.. to access my data but I want to solve this with Context API.

Hope that someone can help me out, I want to become better and understand the Context API here.

My code:

```
state = {
    social_media: [],
    page_home: [],
    loading: true,
};

getCoffee() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('☕'), 2000); // it takes half of a second to make coffee
    });
}

async showData() {
    try {
        const wpSocial = axios(`${ACF_DATA_URL}/options/social_media_data`);
        const wpHome = axios(`${WP_DATA_URL}/pages?slug=home`);

        await this.getCoffee();

        await Promise.all([wpSocial, wpHome]).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                social_media: response[0].data.social_media_data,
                page_home: response[1].data[0],
                loading: false,
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e); // 
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.showData();
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is I want to create one Context API and pass the same state, function ShowData, and GetCoffee() to multiple different components.

How can i do this?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Its simple, create a new context first (context.js)

```
const Context = React.createContext();
```

Create a provider using the above created context (context.js), the provider class will hold state and methods.

```
class Provider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    some_state: 'value',
    some_method: this.method
  }

  method = () => {
    console.log('It works');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider>
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Export both the provider and consumer (context.js)

```
const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
export { Provider, Consumer };
```

Wrap the App component with the provider (app.js), so that every JSX component down the App tree will be able to use the `some_state` and `some_method`

```
import { Provider } from './{some_path}/context';

<Provider>
  <App> ... </App>
</Provider>
```

Finally, consume the value in some component, you have to tell which state properties you want after the declaring the `<Consumer>` component (here we are using both `some_state` and `some_method`)

```
import { Consumer } from './{some_path}/context';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Consumer>
        {({some_state, some_method}) => {
          <button onClick={some_method}>{some_state}</button>
        }
      </Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```